# Chrome struggles to play videos

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg

I have some video files I want to display on a webpage using the HTML5 video player. The videos were sent to me at 1920x1080 in H.254 MP4 format.

Using FFMPEG I have converted them so I have a smaller Mp4 file, an OGV file, and a WebM file using the following commands:

```
ffmpeg -i FILE.mp4 -vcodec h264 FILE.mp4

ffmpeg -i FILE.mp4 -acodec libvorbis -vcodec libtheora -f ogv FILE.ogv

ffmpeg -i FILE.mp4 -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis FILE.webm
```

And then the video is embedded into the page like so:

```
<video preload="metadata" crossorigin="anonymous" poster="poster.jpg" controls playsinline>
    <source src="FILE.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="FILE.ogv" type="video/ogv">
    <source src="FILE.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

However when I click to play the video in Chrome, it stops after a few seconds and then if I click play again it restarts. If I right click and open the video in a new tab I just see a tiny player and not the video e.g.
[image]

The same happens for all three formats. But if I refresh the browser enough times I can get the MP4 file to show up in the new tab though it still suffers from the aforementioned bug of playing for a few seconds before failing.

**I have tested this in Firefox and Safari and it works fine!** *In fact it even works in IE and Edge :D* And I can also play the videos in a player on the machine itself... e.g. QuickTime.

Any ideas why Chrome is acting this way? Or any resolutions? I'm seeing the same behaviour on Chrome for Windows and Mac. Is the way I have converted the videos using FFMPEG in anyway a cause that could affect Chrome but not other browsers?

Chrome version tested on: `Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Output from `ffprobe` as per the comments on the one of the webm files:

```
ffprobe version 3.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-ffplay --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --enable-openssl --disable-lzma --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.3.0/include/openjpeg-2.3 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'FILE.webm':
  Metadata:
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: mp42mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : mp42
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    ENCODER         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:52.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 910 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : Alias Data Handler
      ENCODER         : Lavc57.107.100 libvpx
      DURATION        : 00:00:52.563000000
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : Alias Data Handler
      ENCODER         : Lavc57.107.100 libvorbis
      DURATION        : 00:00:52.568000000
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `ffprobe` on the file you are trying to play in Chrome?  I'm wondering if there might be some issue with the file we can determine from that.

Comment: It may also be a keyframe issue with the source file itself.  I think this is what causes issues where you can't seek to certain spots in a file, but playing up to that point in a file is fine.  Maybe take a look at https://superuser.com/q/908280/152128.  Sorry for spit balling here.

Comment: @zero298 Added output to my post.

Comment: @zero298 What I can't understand is that if there's an issue with the file how come other browsers (including IE) can play it fine? Just Chrome is acting up and failing.

Comment: They all use different video decoders.  That's also why you get varying support between browsers for certain video codecs.  See [Media formats for HTML audio and video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats).  One decoder may gracefully handle certain codec idiosyncrasies while others might be very picky.

Comment: Can you also try playing the video without audio?  Export it again with the `-an` (no audio) option.  It might be an issue with one of the audio streams.  If that doesn't work, try the opposite, only audio.  This should help isolate the issue.

Comment: @zero298 Okies now this is weird! After uploading the site to a server (internal) it works now on Chrome, where as before I was running from localhost. However this is odd as I have some other videos I just tried and they work fine locally. So it's like Chrome is just picky about which videos it will play and which it won't when run on localhost.

Comment: Very strange.  No idea what could be causing that.  Are you sure both local and remote servers are sending the same headers?  Are they both the same server types (apache vs nginx vs node)?

Comment: The only other weird thing that I see is that you set one of your `<source>` to `type="video/ogv"` instead of `video/ogg` (og**g**).

Comment: @zero298 Yeah same server setup. Regarding the OGV... apparently OGV and OGA are the preferred file extensions for video or audio files in OGG format.

Comment: Not solutions but just notes: Don't bother with ogg if you're including webm. For mp4 output add `-movflags +faststart` so the video can begin playback before it is completely downloaded. If you have the time use libvpx-vp9 instead of libvpx (to output VP9 video although Safari may not like it).